# Save UISwitch Value in multiple view controllers and mute App

Tags: uiviewcontroller, return-value, avaudioplayer, uiswitch

I'm currently making a game and everything is going fine except for one simple thing. I'm having a problem with my app sound. When I touch the "Start" Button to play the game, it presents a new View Controller with the game itself and it plays a song. I have another view controller with its settings. Inside it, I have a UISwith that mutes the App. My problem is that when I dismiss that view controller it does not save its state. I tried NSUserDefauts and could not get it working. Maybe I'm not doing it right... If you could help me I would be very appreciated!
Also, I have multiple a AVAudioPlayer (one for the game, another for when the user wins or loses) is there a way to just completely mute the entire app instead of muting every single AVAudioPlayer one at a time?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding muting the sound:

```
- (IBAction)speakerOnOff:(id)sender
{
    static BOOL muted = NO;
    if (muted) {
        [player setVolume:1.0];
    } else {
        [player setVolume:0.0];
    }
    muted = !muted;
}
```

If you have multiple AVAudioPlayer just access the properties of all and setVolume:0.0.

Comment: thank you so much. That works. Also, I have a view controller for the iPhone and another for the iPad. Is there any way I can use the same AVAudioPlayer on both so I can mute them both only with one IBAction on the UISwitch? Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes just connect the UIButton of the iPad layout to the IBAction I've written. You can vote the answer as correct if it helped you :-)

Comment: I will certainly vote, like I always do, but the thing is, the problem is still not solved. The problem is, I wanted to have an UISwitch on my main ViewController and use the IBAction you wrote to mute the sound. But my AVAudioPlayer(s) are on my iPhoneViewController and iPadViewController, so the main ViewController does not recognize the variable "AudioPlayer" used on the iPhone/iPad ViewControllers. How can I share this variables across the ViewControllers or just mute the entire app? This is my problem, If you could help, that would be really awesome. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: You can either add a NSNotificationCenter listener to your iPhone and iPadViewController so when you mute the sound via the ViewController, you post the notification and they mute the sound, or you can make their AVAudioPlayers extern properties to the main ViewController and access them directly via the main View Controller. Note that the first solution is better coding practice.

Comment: Well I tried but I cannot get the NSNotification to be sent to another ViewConrtoller. How can I add a @selector that is on a different ViewController? Either way you tried to help me so I'll go ahead and vote your's as correct.

Comment: You just post the notification from the ViewController. The iPhone and iPad viewcontroller have the listener to the notification and they mute their sound using the method I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I did do that...here's what I did :
In ViewController:
-(IBAction)changeSwitch:(id)sender{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(muteSound) name:@"soundOff" object:nil];
(but it says "Undeclared Selector "muteSound")
on iPhoneViewController I added:
-(IBAction)muteSound:(id)sender{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"soundOff" object:nil];
NSLog(@"muted"); 
[audioPlayer setVolume:0];

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't it finding the method "muteSound"? Thank you...once again.